# Email compliance and validation with RFC 2822, 3.6.2 in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, swiftmailer, symfony-validator

I have an issue while validating a user email address through the [Symfony Email Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/reference/constraints/Email.html) and then trying to send an mail to this user through [Swiftmailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/).

Let's say my user is registering with **name@@gmail.com** (the double **@** is an intentional typo for the example). This is successfully validated by the Email Constraint validation in Symfony, and the user is created in my database.

But when I try to send the mail using Swiftmailer, I get a **500 error**

> Address in mailbox given [name@@gmail.com] does not comply with RFC
>   2822, 3.6.2.

coming from Swiftmailer itself.

Comment: I don't know symfony but `filter_var('name@@gmail.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can enable the [`strict` mode in Symfony's EmailValidator](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Email.html#mode), e.g. like this:

```php
class Author
{
    /**
     * @Assert\Email(
     *     message = "The email '{{ value }}' is not a valid email.",
     *     mode = "strict"
     * )
     */
    protected $email;
}
```

As the docs say:

> Uses the egulias/email-validator library to perform an RFC compliant validation. You will need to install that library to use this mode.

The [egulias/email-validator](https://github.com/egulias/EmailValidator) is also used by SwiftMailer (see Swiftmailer's [composer.json](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/composer.json#L19) and [PathHeader](https://github.com/swiftmailer/swiftmailer/blob/master/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/PathHeader.php#L42)), so this should give you similar validation results.

Comment: For whatever reason, the op posted a link to the 3.4 version of the email constraint.  For 3.4, one would use "strict = true" when configuring.

Comment: Yes, I'm still using SF 3.4 on this project. Thanks guys, perfect answer, I just forgot to scrool down to see the constraint options...